# Remote desktop disappears after login

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

I'm using remote desktop between two XP sessions; out of the blue, it has started playing up: as soon as I've logged in the window simply evaporates (no errors, just gone).

I can still connect to other machines.

Any idea what would cause this to suddenly play up?

Note that I've seen problems with this before, oddly enough with graphics drivers; but I haven't changed anything on the target machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

- Has the target machine out of resources? (Do you know anyone who can have a look at the physical desktop?)
- Has the target machine out of remote connection licences (or whatever the limiting factor is)? I'd have expected a decent error message in that case, admittedly.

Is there anything useful in the event log on either machine?

Comment: If a resource issue and a remote computer, you could use "taskkill" to kill a remote process to free resources.  (IE. firefox.exe)

Answer (score 2):

Like you wrote in your question, I think the driver of the graphics card is the culprit - I mean the driver of the computer where the Remote Desktop client runs.

Even if you haven't changed anything in the video configuration, there may be something new (software, icons, anything...) on the remote machine which causes the video driver to go crazy.

Comment: (do you really mean "server"? i.e. the remote machine?)

Comment: Yes, the RD client on the local machine crashes, because it has to display something "weird" (weird for the video driver) which comes from the remote machine. But this is just an idea.

Comment: comment from [Dave](http://superuser.com/users/14928/dave): Yep, after reading this post I updated the video card drviers (was a Nvidia 8 series) and it worked a treat, thanks guys!

Comment: comment from [Orlando](http://superuser.com/users/20871/orlando): Thanks guys, it also worked for me. I updated my Nvidia drivers.