# Remote desktop session closes immediately after logging in

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote-desktop

I have a Windows7 Ultimate x64 machine that I connect to via RDP from multiple places (a few WinXP/Win7 machines, a few iOS devices using different RDP clients). Everything works like a charm.

But there's this single 32-bit WinXP SP3 laptop that does not work. Specifically, I can connect, I can login, I can even see a glimpse of the desktop, but then the RDP client window just disappears a second or two after showing the desktop. No error messages, no nothing. This same client machine can RDP into other boxes just fine, so the client is not completely broken.

I am pretty sure this is caused by installing some fairly recent windows updates -- if I restore the machine from backup, it works fine until I reinstall those updates. And I would strongly prefer to have the updates installed, for obvious reasons...

Any ideas on how to diagnose/fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you downloaded the updated RDP client on your XP laptop?  AFAIK, it doesn't ship with the client needed for RDP into a Win7 machine.

Comment: I have the same thing happening, but both machines are win7 pro.

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/6855/remote-desktop-disappears-after-login,

Answer (score 1):

It's a pain, but try installing each update one at a time until you find the one causing the problem. That might give you a better clue on what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Check that remote machine's Event Viewer for clues.  I've had this happen when I've updated a video driver remotely; I was not able to RDP in after it rebooted.

Comment: Nothing. Neither on the "server" nor on the client. :(

Answer (score 0):

This question is relatively old at the time of this answer, and there are probably several solutions given these symptoms.

Having had the same issue; the problem was **conflicting IPs on the network**.

Once the IP problem was resolved (in this case the was a device with a static IP address in the same range as those being dished out by the DHCP) - the problem went away and the sessions were very stable.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue unnistalling this update: KB2984972. Hope it helps.